# how to divide string in the text field into two paragraphs? pls suggest any idea

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I have a field,  `Description__C`. when ever we enter a string (suppose if entered 140 characters string) in this field and save this, it should divide the string into each paragraph of 50 characters, in this case 3 paragraphs.

**Ex:** I have entered "Unfortunately, I don't see away to get at these fields via the API.  You'd have to write some javascript"

The out put should be:

I have entered "Unfortunately, I don't see away to get at these fi

elds via the API.  You'd have to write some javascript".

The output should be displayed in separate line of 50 charecters.

Please share any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to **write a trigger** here **on before insert and update**.

In that you need to put the logic to divide the string into chunks of 50 characters.Then apply new line characters between them.

See this:[Save newline in Text field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74215/save-newline-in-text-field)